# How to get my page onto Google's, Yahoo's, and other search engines' first page?

Tags: seo

I want to list my web page in Google, Yahoo and other popular search engines and get on the first page. What can I do? Can you please tell me the ways of SEO and suggest any tutorials I would need to become good at SEO?

Comment: This is a better fit for webmasters - it should be automagically transferred there soon.

Comment: I made this community wiki because no definitively "correct" answer(s).

Answer (score 5):

There actually is very little to SEO contrary to what many will have you believe. SEO is mostly:

- quality content
- usability
- accessibility
- semantic markup

If your site is built with the four principles in mind your site will be optimized for the search engines. If you have to go back and "SEO your website" then you made mistakes when you first built it and only are fixing it (or making it worse if your changes are only being made with the search engines in mind).

Once a properly built website is launched the only real SEO to be done is to utilize tools like [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) to help facilitate the indexing of your site and find potential errors or problems that the search engines have with your site. Then from there it's continually adding new quality content (if applicable) and marketing (seeking links is marketing).

Reading [Google Webmaster](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/) and SEO blogs are a good idea as is [Matt Cutts blog](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog). I don't recommend seobook, seochar,or most other sites like them.  They want you to believe that SEO is constantly changing and you need to spend a lot of time and effort (and money) to rank well. It's not true. The basics of SEO hasn't changed in a very long time. As a rule, if an SEO site is trying to take your money they probably aren't a good source of information. If you're looking for a good site checkout [websitepublisher.net](http://websitepublisher.net). It's got accurate and unbiased information and I highly recommend it. Especially the [SEO guide](http://www.websitepublisher.net/seo-guide/)).

As for your question, getting on the first page of a search engine can be easy or difficult depending on the search term you are aiming for. The more competitive the longer it will take to accomplish and the more difficult it will be (if it can even be done at all). Less competitive search terms are easier to rank well for and can be accomplished more quickly. They also will deliver less traffic. Either way you need to be patient and work hard. There are no shortcuts or special tools that will make you rank well. Those four principles combined with good marketing and patience will ultimately pay off.

Comment: Posted from my phone so links will be added later.

Comment: This is all very true. I used to maintain a couple of websites - a blog and a forum - when I was a Microsoft MVP and got on the first page of all the search engines with no thought or "plan" by just having reasonably clear and easy to use websites with good content. I hadn't even *heard* of SEO at that point until someone asked me how I got ranked so highly in the search engines.

Answer (score 1):

There is A LOT of information out there about SEO, and it can be a bit intimidating at first.

So I suggest you start with a simple explanation that I watched in a video just a couple of days ago.

Check the video [SEO Your Web Page for Google](http://www.wordtracker.com/academy/seo-your-web-page-for-google-video) on wordtracker academy. You can ignore their plug to buy their product, but the general principles are covered and explained quite well.

Then you will have a direction to search onward and learn more about the topic. I suggest checking websites and blogs on [seomoz.org](http://www.seomoz.org/), [seochat.com](http://www.seochat.com/), [wolf-howl.com](http://www.wolf-howl.com/) and many others.

And Matt Cutts appearing in videos on the [Youtube Google Webmaster Help Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleWebmasterHelp).