# How to increase Google page rank of your website/blog?

Tags: seo

OK so as far as I know to have good PR your website must have

1. Good content/articles
2. Many back-links
3. Good HTML code.

What else?

What should one do to increase his/her website's Google Page-Rank?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To improve the value of Google's proprietary PageRank<sup>TM</sup>, you just need links. It's solely based on the number and quality of links pointing to the specific page.

To improve the ranking in search engine results pages (SERPs) there are hundreds of ranking factors, including the PageRank, relevance of the page, relevance of pages linking to you, good titles/headings, and a small factor is page speed.

Good HTML code doesn't really make a difference, aside from the case where the HTML is *so bad* that a search engine cannot read the page.

Answer (score 3):

To increase PR (e.g. PageRank) you need to get more links to your site. The higher the PR of the page linking to you the more *potential* PR you may receive. I say potential because the amount of PR "passed" from the linking page to your page is affected by how many other links are on that page. The more links on that page, the more the PR is distributed amongst those links and thus less is passed to your page. PR can also not be passed by pages that use "nofollow" on their links.

FYI, point #1 has no direct affect on PR and #3 has no effect at all. #1 has an indirect affect as it encourages people to link to your site. But good content itself does not affect PR as PR is only affected by links.

If you want to increase your page's ranking, different from PageRank, see [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/how-to-get-my-page-onto-googles-yahoos-and-other-search-engines-first-page/4670#4670). (I'll also explicitly say go and get links to your pages as, even though that is common sense marketing, because it can have a significant effect on rankings, it is commonly recommended by others as "the thing to do". Expect to see lots of people saying that both here and everywhere you ask this question. Just keep in mind that quality links are what you want. Not quantity).