# Increasing the pagerank to my blogs index page, removing the links to posts

Tags: seo, wordpress, pagerank, links

I want to increase page rank on my main index blog page and categories.

If i remove the links to my posts from my index page and have only links to categories, will that help? Anyone tried it?

Ty

Comment: You need to clarify, do you mean Page Rank or page rank? They are two totally different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increase your PageRank see [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5012/how-to-increase-google-page-rank-of-your-website-blog) for how to do that

> If i remove the links to my posts from
>   my index page and have only links to
>   categories, will that help?

No. That's not how PR works. A page's PR is not changed by the number of links ***on*** it. It is changed by the number and quality of links ***to*** it.

I wouldn't worry about PR. Its role in Google's algorithm is clearly diminished. Instead focus on improving your content and attracting quality links.

Comment: I'm not a newbie myself, ty for the answer. The way i see it, pagerank is like a glass, depending of how many external links you have. It spills over the site, depending on how the internal liks are setup, some pages can become more important then others.. basicaly you can manipulate which page of your site appears in serps on which keywords.. just wondered if anyoneelse did it

Comment: That's not quite accurate. PR is not a measure of link quantity but of link quality. Not all links are equal. Also, PR is from every link (that isn't nofollow, etc) whether it is internal or external. Also, what you're (mostly) talking about is called PR sculpting. That's not a bad thing to do, but like I said, it's not going to make a real difference in your rankings. Additionally, you cannot really manipulate which page appears in the SERPs as you don't have control over lots of variables that determine that. You can try to influence it, but you don't have any real control.

Comment: See my comment above. Your question isn't clear whether you mean PageRank or page rank. They are very different things so we may be talking about two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you concerning yourself with pagerank in the first place?

Do not try to game the system.  PLus the page rank meter is not the true page rank of your site.

Build many dofollow incoming links from a variety of sources to gain rank to your home page.